# Finding intersection of two lines in this figure?

Tags: line, intersection

I have two points B(x1,y1) , C(x2,y2), then I calculate the corrdinate of two more points J(xdd,ydd) and k(xgg,ygg) know I want to find the coordinate of yellow star point which is the intersection of line JK and BC, How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
xdd= x1(index1)+(DeltaX*D_CL)/D +(DeltaY/D)*sqrt(r^2-D_CL^2);
ydd= y1(index1)+(DeltaY*D_CL)/D-(DeltaX/D)*sqrt(r^2-D_CL^2);
xgg= x1(index1)+(DeltaX*D_CL)/D-(DeltaY/D)*sqrt(r^2-D_CL^2);
ygg=y1(index1)+(DeltaY*D_CL)/D+(DeltaX/D)*sqrt(r^2-D_CL^2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right the star is in the middle of A and D or B and C. You do not need to consider J and K.

```
P  = 1/2 (A+D) = 1/2 (B+C)
```